# Как исправить ошибку при запуске проектов в Visual Studio Community 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Иногда при запуске проектов (любых) 2015 студия намертво виснет, и приходится убивать ее через диспетчер. При повторном запуске этого же проекта вылазит такая ошибка:

[image]

Содержание "Вывод":

> Обнаружена ошибка при открытии связанных документов во время последней загрузки решения. Загрузка документов пропускается при загрузке решения во избежание повторения ошибки.

Так же сбиваются все вкладки в редакторе которые я открывал ранее.

Переустановка не помогает, в 2013 версии все нормально. Может кто то встречался с такой ошибкой, и нашел решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для VS2012Express:

- Откройте папку `\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0`
  и удалите в ней папку `ComponentModelCache`

Для VS2012 Professional:

- Откройте папку `\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`
  и удалите в ней папку `ComponentModelCache`

Первый запуск может занять длительное время из-за пересборки кэша. После этого все будет работать.